# Anonymous method with return

Tags: c#, lambda

Please tell me what is wrong and how to write annonymous method with return for this impementation

```
public class Test 
{
    public string Implisity { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        /*Here is a problem */
        var variable = Method(delegate(IList<string> i, List<string> j){ return new Test(){Implisity = i[j.IndexOf("Implisity")]}; });
    }

    public static List<T> Method<T>(Func<IList<string>, IList<string>, T> staff) { return new List<T>(){staff(new List<string>() {"1","2"}, new List<string>(){"Explisity","Implisity"})}; }
}
```

this is a flat method what as me need to make annonymous

```
    public static Test Annonymous(IList<string> i, List<string> j) 
    { 
        var obj = new Test() { Implisity = i[j.IndexOf("Implisity")] };
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: omg. Can you at least try making your code readable? Line break is a thing, you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `Method(...)` method expects a `Func<...>` with different parameter types: it expects a method that takes two `IList<string>` objects, while you are making a delegate that takes an `IList<string>` and a `List<string>`

```
var variable = Method(
    delegate(IList<string> i, IList<string> j) {
    //                        ^
        return new Test() {
            Implisity = i[j.IndexOf("Implisity")]
         };
    }
);
```

To avoid issues like this in the future, use implicit typing, like this:

```
var variable = Method( (i, j) => new Test { Implisity = i[j.IndexOf("Implisity")] } );
```

In this example, the compiler knows what the parameter types of the function must be from the signature of the `Method(...)` method, so it implicitly assigns the types to `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 var variable = Method((i, j) => new Test() { Implisity = i[j.IndexOf("Implisity")] });
```

A [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) is an unnamed method written in place of a delegate instance.
The compiler immediately converts the lambda expression to either:

- A delegate instance.
- An expression tree, of type `Expression<TDelegate>`, representing the
  code inside the lambda expression in a traversable object model. This
  allows the lambda expression to be interpreted later at runtime